# The timestamp(unix) i am creating locally in flutter is 8 minutes later

Tags: android, flutter, dart, datetime, timestamp

Hello every one i have an issue that the timestamp (unix) i am creating locally in editor is 8 minutes later and when i am creating online it is fine mean uptodate. so what to do now?

Tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Can you check if your device is in sync with internet time ?

Comment: Love your suggestion, thanks it worked for me.

Comment: But the problem is when I close the DateTime window, it again disconnects.